# Switch rotation between objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation

I’ve worked out a function that rotates objects around a main object, like planets around a  sun.

I want to be able to change the  object that the other objects rotate around  at the click of a button. Example, I’ve got objects A, B and C. B and C rotate around A. But I want to be able to have C rotate around B, while B stays rotating around A. I’m trying to work this out in this code:

```
var objectX = "black";
function switchObject(){
  objectX = "blue";
}

function rotation(coorX, coorY, object) {
    object.side +=  (1.0 / object.speed); 
    var ang = object.side * 2.0 * Math.PI / 180.0; 
    var r = object.spin;

    return {
        x: Math.cos(ang) * r - Math.sin(ang) * r + coorX, 
        y: Math.sin(ang) * r + Math.cos(ang) * r + coorY 
    };
  }  

  function rotationball ( circle ) {
    var x, y, x_black, y_black, e, newpos;
    e = document.getElementById ( circle );
    x_black = parseFloat ( document.getElementById ( objectX ).getAttribute ( "cx" ) );
    y_black = parseFloat ( document.getElementById ( objectX ).getAttribute ( "cy" ) );
    newpos = rotation( x_black, y_black, ball[circle] );

    e.setAttribute ( "cx", newpos.x );
    e.setAttribute ( "cy", newpos.y );
    }
```

I already know how to easily switch through which object is the object that the others rotate around by the objectX variable you see in the code. But that happens instantly, and I need it to be gradually, which infers a lot more difficult mathemathical code I think.

My question to you is:

What should my code have to look like in order for the red object to start rotating around the blue object, while the blue object keeps rotating around the black one. This needs to be done gradually though, in numerous rotations. I appreciate any help that comes my way, be it some of the code I would need or pointers in the right direction! Thanks in advance.

Here's my [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/571hcybw/)

PS: I was also going to program that each added planet would be positioned a bit farther from the central point (the sun) than the previously added planet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wrote relative move ball. Just set relative coordinates for second "planet", mathematics remains the same, just change 
[frame of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_of_reference). please see [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Anton_S_Pilipenko/571hcybw/3/)

```
rotationball("red"); 
relativeRotationBall("blue", "red");

var ball = { 
  blue: {speed: 1.2,    spin: 100,  side: 0.0} , 
  red:  {speed: 2.2,    spin: 200,  side: 0.0} // speed up
};
```

**Update:**
  Change reference frame on click switch button.

```
function preSetObjectRotation(dedfaultObject, frameReference) {    
    var self = this;
      this.defaultObject = dedfaultObject;
      this.defaultFrameReference = frameReference;
      this.setFrameReference = function (frameReference) {
          self.defaultFrameReference = frameReference;
      };
      this.relativeRotationBall = function relativeRotationBall () {
        var e, newpos;
        e = document.getElementById ( self.defaultObject );
        newpos = relativeRotation( self.defaultFrameReference, ball[self.defaultObject] );
        e.setAttribute ( "cx", newpos.x );
        e.setAttribute ( "cy", newpos.y );
      }  
 }
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Anton_S_Pilipenko/571hcybw/6/)

**Update 2**
Auto switch when dots on one line, in isEclipse function ([JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Anton_S_Pilipenko/571hcybw/16/)  )

Comment: This works for the most part, thank you. But I still am trying to figure out how to gradually switch between the frame of reference.
Would you know how to do that? So that relativeRotationBall("blue", "red"); changes from "black" to "red".

Comment: Thank you, for helping me out, twice! I definitely appreciate it and your code helps me out a lot.